# how to create multiple excel sheets

Tags: c#, asp.net

well i have to creat just one excel file and 2 sheets both are fill using a 2 diferent DataTable, it gives the name the user only has to click save, the next code allows me to seend one datatable to one sheet (i am using C#, asp.net, and NOT using Visual Studio, i am writing in the Notepad my code):

```
string name2="Centroids";
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in _myDataTable2.Rows)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < _myDataTable2.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
            }
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    context.Response.ContentType = "text2/csv";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name2 + ".csv");
```

but i have no idea how to creat the second sheet and use the second DataTable, any ideas of how to find a solution, this way the user has only to save and donwload only one document and not save as many DataTable are in the programa

Comment: CSV files can't have multiple sheets.

Comment: @JAB thank i have no idea that it was not posible, no now up to look for another answer

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to explore the possibility of using EPPlus. In my experience, using Response object has lot of constraints and take too much development effort to generate Excel file.

Url:
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should use open source libraries for generating native excel files, there is no way you can create two sheets with csv.

Use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) (xls) or / and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (xlsx) and fully control your excel export, in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569827/351383 you can see example of creating excel file from DataTable with EPPlus. You can edit that method to accept DataTable list and create new sheets for each table, it's simple, just :

```
ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool LlenarExcelxlsx(List<DatosEntidad> listaOrigen)
{
    bool exito = false;
    string[] tipoLista = { "A", "B", "C" };
    string nombreArchivo = @"D:\prueba.xlsx";

    IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    using (FileStream fileData = new FileStream(nombreArchivo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < tipoLista.Length; k++)
        {
            List<DatosEntidad> listaDestino = listaOrigen
                .Where(c => c.tipo == tipoLista[k]).ToList();

            DataTable dt = ToDataTable(listaDestino);

            ISheet sheetx = wb.CreateSheet("Res_" + tipoLista[k] + k);
            ICreationHelper cH = wb.GetCreationHelper();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                IRow row = sheetx.CreateRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
                {
                    ICell cell = row.CreateCell(j);
                    cell.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        wb.Write(fileData);
        exito = true;
    }
    return exito;
}
```

Comment: Este código está probado y funciona correctamente a partir de una lista origen.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to provide some explanation of the code and the changes you made? That would be useful.