# After saving xlsx file using NPOI, when I open xlsx file, it says file corrupt

Tags: c#, npoi

```
xlWorksheet.GetRow(1).GetCell(2).SetCellValue("Hello");
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("Test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   XLWorkBook.Write(file);
   file.Close();
}
```

I used this code to write excel file. After writing the excel, when I open excel file manually it is corrupted.
I am using NPOI binary 2.1.3.1
Please tell how to avoid excel getting corrupted.

Comment: having `using ()`, you don't need to `file.Close()`, it will be closed autmatically

Comment: What is the type of your `xlWorkseet`?

Comment: Is their anyone using NPOI to write excel sheet using Xlsx. I need opensource dll to access xlsx file. Is their any alternate open source software available..

Comment: OpenXml SDK from Microsoft. It is free and very powerfull. But NPOI should also work with xlsx, as with xls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079956/does-npoi-have-support-to-xlsx-format

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `file.Flush();` before `file.Close();`:

```
xlWorksheet.GetRow(1).GetCell(2).SetCellValue("Hello");
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("Test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   XLWorkBook.Write(file);
   file.Flush();
   file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Its not working. When I use flush, It is not allowing me to write excel file if I use Loop to write excel

Comment: @Kriez: Your code doesn't contain a loop. Please adjust your question to show your real code.

Comment: I have written the above code in one method and i will call method multiple times. Is their bug in NPOI for saving xlsx. Because xls file is fine with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using file.Close() in a repeat loop.

Plus, I would recommend opening the file, doing the looping, and then flushing and closing the file.

This method is much better time-wise because repeatedly opening and closing a file consumes a lot of time and requires a trip to the drive every time.