# ASP Table to Excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel

When viewing ASPX in website, I got a table with few text in the cells, e.g.:

```
tab.Rows[1].Cells[1].innerHtml = "Booked :"
```

(In a lot of rows and cells but with different text in each cell)

Now I just want to click a button, and data in the table will be downloaded into an Excel file.

Table ID : tab

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Table tbl = new Table();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tcel = new TableCell();
        tcel.Text = "id";
        tr.Cells.Add(tcel);

        TableCell tcel1 = new TableCell();
        tcel1.Text = "id1";
        tr.Cells.Add(tcel1);

        tab.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = "ExportExcel.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    //DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
    //dgGrid.DataSource = tbl;
    //dgGrid.DataBind();

    //Get the HTML for the control.             
    tab.RenderControl(hw);
    //Write the HTML back to the browser.
    //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Modified with watraplion answer, but still not answer..
Error at:

```
DataTable dt = dt; //Use of unassigned local variable 'dt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

aspx Design View :

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
          <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
           </asp:Table>
      </div>
      <div>
           <asp:Button ID="btnExport" onclick="btnExport_Click" Text="Export" runat="server">
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

aspx.cs ( code behind )

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tcel = new TableCell();
        tcel.Text = "id";
        tr.Cells.Add(tcel);

        TableCell tcel1 = new TableCell();
        tcel1.Text = "id1";
        tr.Cells.Add(tcel1);

        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "ExportExcel.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        //Get the HTML for the control.             
        Table1.RenderControl(hw);
        //Write the HTML back to the browser.
        //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.End();
     }
```

Comment: sorry, I think no need to change that,
but here got error DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();

Comment: it asked me to resolve using System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid or System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid...

Comment: Are you dynamically creating HTML Table on code behind file or using <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table> in aspx page??

Comment: I created the rows and cells in the design view then added innerhtml to each cell with text dynamically

Comment: Are you expecting similar this one?? else please show ur aspx page code & way you append the text in the table.

Comment: //Table tbl = new Table();  --> its a comment or code?

 tab.Rows.Add(tr); //Error here

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: can you remove your above code & edit with "aspx" page code & the way you dynamically added text code?

Comment: remove button click code which you mentioned on ur ques & show ur design view code.

Answer (score 0):

First to say that this what you are trying to do is not export to excel, but you send a html with a wrong headers to trick browser to open this content with excel.

This solution has many problems, excel it self will warn user that content is different from extension, because you send html and your response headers are saying that this is a excel file. And I can bet that some antimalware software on client or something similar on server, will block this response since serving different content than declared in headers is known malware behavior.

It's far more better and easier to use dedicated excel library, for example [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), look here for ASP.NET ashx handler that exports DataTable to real excel file :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569827/351383