# Export Excel from grid not working on Ajax Model PopUp

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am trying to export grid data to excel but it is not working in IE8.I am using a Ajax Modal PopUp dialog box containing 2 buttons 'ok' and 'close'.On Ok click i want to download excel file.it works fine in Mozilla but in IE its not working.I am using below code. please suggest me how to do that?Also when i open file first it show warning before opening file how to handle that?

```
  Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    string filename = "Checkout";
     Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".adt");

    Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
    Response.Write("<head>");
    Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
    Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
    Response.Write("<x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>");
    Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
    Response.Write("<x:Print>");
    Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
    Response.Write("</x:Print>");
    Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
    Response.Write("</xml>");
    Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
    Response.Write("</head>");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
    gv.RenderControl(hw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: How is it not working in IE ? Please describe

Comment: IN Mozilla a pop up massage appears to download or open file.but nothing happen in case of IE

Answer (score 0):

You get warning because tehnically speaking this is not export to excel, but you send a html with a wrong headers to trick browser to open this content with excel.

Better use native Excel library and generate real Excel file on the server, for example [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), it's open source and doesn't require excel on server.

Here is the example of ashx handler that generates excel file from DataTable

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569827/351383